# How to wait for query to end in aws amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, graphql, aws-amplify

I query 'product' on one of my screens using the following function

```
const getProduct = async () => {

try{
      if(userId){
await DataStore.query(Product, c=>c.userID("eq", userId)).then(setProducts)
}
    }catch(e){
      return
    }
  };
```

But what I want is to display something like an activity indicator and wait for the query to finish and then display the products. How can I do this?

Comment: enable indicator before query and set it disabled within the setProducts

Comment: @Sajeetharan Yes this is working thanks. There is no problem implementing this in a production app right?

Comment: what do you mean by production app? no issues

Answer (score 0):

Your code above should be inside a useEffect() hook that will run any time the userId changes. That hook can return multiple states: loading, error, the data...

To get the above in a very well tested, easier to read, package with bells & whistles (e.g. caching), look into [React Query](https://tanstack.com/query/v4).

Pseudo-code:

```
function ExampleComponent() {
  const { isLoading, error, data } = useQuery(['products'], () =>
    // fetch data here
  )

  if (isLoading) return 'Loading...'

  if (error) return 'An error has occurred: ' + error.message

  return (
    <div>
      <!-- map over your data here -->
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I think that I can also use something like react-promise-tracker to do this.

Comment: @hewa Looks like the react-promise-tracker library hasn't been updated in over 3 years. Use React Query. It's one of the most popular and well supported react libraries around and solves the exact issue you asked about.

Comment: My personal recommendation: Write the solution as a useEffect() just for fun and learning. Then throw the code away and add React Query.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing extra needed to enable indicator, it's just a visual representation on the client to show that request is in progress. You can enable indicator before query and set it disabled within the setProducts